# isotope filter using value on divs with data-*

Tags: filter, custom-data-attribute, jquery-isotope

Im trying to filter divs by data attribute rather than class using isotope... im not sure how isotope works and there appears to be nothing in the documentation that references filtering data attributes and not just classes?!

Im sure i will slap my self with the answer...

but this is as far as I have got:

```
var $grid = $('.isotope').isotope({
itemSelector: '.isotope-item'
});

$('#item-filter-select').on('change', function () {
  var el = this.value;
  $grid.isotope({ filter: el });  
});

<div id="filters">

    <h4>Geschenkideen</h4>
      <select id="item-filter-select">
        <option value="*" >Show All</option>
        <option value="clothes" >Clothing</option>
        <option value="jewelry" >Jewelry</option>
        <option value="misc" >Miscellaneous</option>
      </select>

</div>

<div class="isotope">

  <div class="isotope-item" data-price="23" data-type="misc">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/1.jpg" />23
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="400" data-type="misc">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/2.jpg" />400
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="12" data-type="jewelry">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/3.jpg" />12
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item clothes" data-price="8" data-type="clothes">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/4.jpg" />8
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="144" data-type="misc">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/5.jpg" />144
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="70" data-type="misc">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/6.jpg" />70
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="445" data-type="jewlery">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/3.jpg" />445
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="64" data-type="misc">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/2.jpg" />64
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="21" data-type="misc">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/5.jpg" />21
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="82.50" data-type="misc">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/1.jpg" />82.50
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="25" data-type="jewelry">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/3.jpg" />25
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="100" data-type="misc">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/6.jpg" />100
  </div>

   <div class="isotope-item" data-price="30" data-type="misc">
    <img src="http://unit60.com/vendo/img/shop/2.jpg" />30
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen:
http://codepen.io/unit60/pen/vXyAzj

HELLLLP!!! :)

Comment: ive changed the itemSelector to '[data-type]', but still no cigar :(

Answer (score 1):

ok... I have one answer that works, probably not the most elegant but here we go:

```
 var $grid = $('.isotope').isotope({
 itemSelector: '[data-type]'
});

$('#item-filter-select').change( function () {
  var el = this.value;
  var fel;
  if(el!='*'){
   fel = "[data-type='" + el + "']"
 }else{
   fel = "*"
 }
 $grid.isotope({ filter: fel });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yay... I changed the code a bit so that I could combine filters:

```
var filters = {};
$('.item-filter-select').on( 'change',function() {
  var $this = $('option:selected');
  var $parent = $(this);
  var level = $(this).parent().find('select option:selected');
  // get group key
  var $buttonGroup = $parent.parents('.select-group');
  var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
  // set filter for group
  filters[ filterGroup ] = level.data('value');
  // combine filters
  var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });  
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
  var value = '';
  for ( var prop in obj ) {
    value += obj[ prop ];
  }
  return value;
}
```

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/unit60/pen/ORbdWE